# How to automatically exclude search results from bin/obj/debug/release folders in Rider IDE?

Tags: rider

I've got a solution with maybe 10+ projects and each of them have their own bin/obj folder - Rider IDE lately seems to be searching through those folders as well when I make solution searches - Is there a way to exclude/hide those results?

I would assume this should be something the IDE did automatically, maybe my settings have changed?

Comment: About which kind of project are you talking? For a .NET 7 web app I cannot reproduce

Comment: As far as I know, there is an open bug for this. Upvote it: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/RIDER-2173